# Why is my class attributes not being printed to the console?

Tags: c#, class, attributes

Hi I'm new here and was hoping to get some guidance on figuring out why I am not getting the expected output. I am following a tutorial about on C# and I've gotten to the topic of creating and using classes. Here is the specific video link starting at the right minute mark. https://youtu.be/GhQdlIFylQ8?t=12868

**1. Problem**
When I run my program the terminal outputs 1 follow by a line break. It is supposed to output a sting called "Harry Potter".

**2. What I've tried**
I've tried to remove the 'public' from each class attributes to see if it made a difference.
I've tried to print out the class attribute .author instead of the .title

**3. Code**

**Here is my program code:**

```
using System;

namespace Giraffe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) // method or function (contaier for code) this is the mehtod that gets executed
        {
            // thi is a book object. an actual physical book inside the progam an instance 
            Book book1 = new Book();

            // accessing the books attribute by writing book1.'title' 'author' 'pages'
            // Defining the attributes with variables
            book1.title = "Harry Potter";
            book1.author = "JK Rowling";
            book1.pages = 400;

            Console.WriteLine(book1.title);

            Console.ReadLine();
           
        }

        
    
    }
}
```

[Program.cs with terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBVz9.png)

**Here is my Book class code:**

```
using System;
namespace Giraffe
{
    public class Book
    {
        // define a series of class attributes essentially varibales that hold informaiton that describes what a book is.
        // template/blueprint for the data type of a book
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;
    }
}
```

[Book.cs the class file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JgRW.png)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you're running the correct program? Saved the file before compiling?

Comment: I cannot see any problem. Try rebuild the project.

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine! "Harry Potter" printed in the terminal window.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the bug can't be reproduced and the code you provided seems to work fine. Please try to better explain your issue, your dev env and the data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: HI thanks everyone for the help really appreciate the kind and swift responses. I've added 2 screenshots so you can see the terminal output I got. Maybe something went wrong with the saving so it's not compelling correctly. Maybe I'll try to rebuild can't seem to understand why I get 1 followed by a line break output. Thanks again :)

Comment: I see you use an editor that is not Visual Studio neither VSCode... Did you try to put the code in the same file ? Try that even if it seems absurd. Also try with MonoDevelop or VSCode or VS.

Comment: Some troubleshooting advice:  Delete the Giraffe.exe executable from the disk (assuming that's what the exe is called, based on the namespace.)  You may not be running the code you think you are.  When you are running the executable, use the task manager to determine the full path to the executable that is actually running.  You should be able to comment out all the code of Main and rebuild and see that your program does nothing.  Alternatively, insert an `#error foo` somewhere and see that the compiler is indeed compiling the code you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I figured it out. There was some error in the brackets that the IDE kept throwing so I deleted all the code in the Book.cs file and got the brackets right before writing code inside of them.